# How to convert a function defined outside the tasks.py to a Celery task and make the Celery worker to process it in Django

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am trying to use Celery in my Django Project say "**MySite**" . My directory structure is as follows

```
mysite
  - applications
    - api
      -tasks.py
      -urls.py
      -apps.py
      -__init__.py
      -v0
        -__init__.py
        -urls.py
        -views.py
        -utils.py 
      -v1
        -__init__.py
        -urls.py
        -views.py
        -utils.py
    - backbone
      -tasks.py
      -urls.py
      -apps.py
      -views.py
      -models.py
      -__init__.py
  -mysite
    - settings.py
```

I have two applications **api** and **backbone**. I have created **tasks.py** in **api** directory which has various Celery tasks defined. I have various functions defined in the **utils.py** of **v0** and **v1** directories. The above-mentioned structure is just a mere representation of the actual project. The project is much bigger and complicated.

I have funtion say **func1** in **v0/utils.py**

```
def func1:
    #code
```

How can I convert **func1** in **utils.py** to a Celery task without moving the location of **func1** or importing it into **tasks.py** ?. I just want to modify **func1** so that it behaves like a celery task and I should be able to apply **retry** options etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new task in your `tasks.py` module (`my_celery_task_function()`) and from there call your utils functions, (`util_function_1()` and `util_function_2()`)

try something like this

```
#v0/utils.py
def util_function_1():
    # your code
    pass

# v1/utils.py
def util_function_2():
    # your code
    pass


#api/tasks.py
@app.task
def my_celery_task_function():
    from v1.utils import util_function_1
    from v2.utils import util_function_2
    util_function_1()
    util_function_2()
```

---

**UPDATE-1**
here is the example. You could add ***any valid parameter*** to the **`@app.tasks()`** decorator.

```
# v0/utils.py
def func1():
    # your code
    pass


# api/tasks.py
@app.task(bind=True, default_retry_delay=30 * 60)
def my_celery_task_function_1(self, *args, **kwargs):
    from v1.utils import func1
    func1()
```

Comment: It seems to be working. But how can I invoke both functions separately in different locations say If I want to apply `delay` to  `util_function_1()` and call it in `views.py` . How can I add celery's `retry` options to `util_function_1()` If it is imported from source to `tasks.py`?

Comment: Write two celery tasks and call it whereever you want

Comment: So I guess there is no option to make changes to the function in its original location and convert it into celery task. Right?

Comment: Oh..oh... I'm a little bit confused with your actual requirement. Can you elaborate about your ***actual requirement***?

Comment: @AlbinAntony Check my *UPDATE-1* section